# Where can I find a reference list of DOM methods(?) such as appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm looking for a list of things such as appendChild() or createElement() but I assumed they were called event methods but when I search for such a thing, I don't really find what I'm looking for. I've tried searching JS events, event handlers, DOM, DOM events, Dom handlers, Dom methods etc......

What are they called and how do I find a list of them?

Answer (score 1):

DOM APIs are what you need. `querySelectorAll`, `addEventListener`, `removeChild` - these are all different DOM methods.

The MDN document is one of the best places for information on the DOM, and many other aspects of front-end development. [Start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

[This MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Events) guide on event handling is also excellent

Comment: Another good resources is [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, you have the [EventTarget interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), that provides the method `addEventListener()` and let you to attach unlimited [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Additionally, the [Web API DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) provides other interfaces like Document for DOM manipulation (e.g. element selection like `querySelector`).